# How to create space at the end of LongListSelector

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, longlistselector

how can I create some blank space at the end of a `LongListSelector`. When I scroll to the very end I am unable to clearly read the last item.
When I use margin the LLS automatically gets smaller. So that does not suite it.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lITAf.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an empty control as ListFooter. For example:

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
    <StackPanel Height="50"></StackPanel>
</phone:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
```